# SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("submitted")

Tags: python

My code is:

```
print "submitted"
```

but it doesn't output.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Prob. is Python 3+.  Try thins `print('submitted')

Comment: I am using Python V3. Thank you it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because in Python 3, you must wrap the string with parenthesis.

Your code should say:

```
print("submitted")
```

This should work with parenthesis. Your code would have been accepted in Python 2.